# Permission denied to access property 'href' (same domain, FF only)

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, iframe

I am working on a project for my work's website that involves embedding PDFs into an iFrame. These PDFs have links to PDFs in them (same domain), and I need to keep track of the current URL they are on so that I can show an "ad" for the book the PDF came from.

Relevant section of code:

```
            function ShowResults() { 
                       var gender = document.getElementById('gender').selectedIndex;
                       var level = document.getElementById('level').selectedIndex;
                       switch (gender) { 
                          case 0: switch (level) {  
                                     case 0: document.getElementById('results').src = "../dropdown/elementary_male.pdf";
                                             break;
                                     case 1: document.getElementById('results').src = "../dropdown/middle_male.pdf";
                                             break;
                                     case 2: document.getElementById('results').src = "../dropdown/high_male.pdf";
                                             break;
                                     case 3: document.getElementById('results').src = "../dropdown/college_male.pdf";
                                             break;
                                  };
                                  break;
                          case 1: switch (level) {  
                                     case 0: document.getElementById('results').src = "../dropdown/elementary_female.pdf";
                                             break;
                                     case 1: document.getElementById('results').src = "../dropdown/middle_female.pdf";
                                             break;
                                     case 2: document.getElementById('results').src = "../dropdown/high_female.pdf";
                                             break;
                                     case 3: document.getElementById('results').src = "../dropdown/college_female.pdf";
                                             break;
                                  };
                                  break;
                        }
                    }
```

I am wanting to get the URL that the iFrame "results" is on. I am testing it out by alerting `document.getElementById('results').contentWindow.location.href` every two seconds. This fails in Firefox with the message `Error: Permission denied to access property 'href'`, but it works fine in Chrome (no such error). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is everything served from the same host/port?

Comment: Yes. The code works in Chrome, so it thinks it's alright. :P

Comment: So I've worked with this more and it works fine IF the src of the frame is NOT a PDF. Is there a way to get the src of the frame when a PDF is embedded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I am trying to read the URL of the iFrame when the iFrame contains only an embedded PDF. Firefox for some reason doesn't like this. In my specific circumstance, I can get away with converting the PDFs into HTML documents and use those, avoiding the issue altogether (as embedding HTML documents work fine).